# Fill Data into DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I want to fill data table like following image [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aqbv.png).
I tried to get that format by the following code.

**What I Tried**:
Created Class like

```
 public class SomeDetails
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public List<string> SetA{ get; set; }
    public List<string> SetB{ get; set; }
}
```

and code:
I created one method which takes parameters user ,SetA,SetB(here Seta, SetB are Lists). I need to call following method of code for multiple times.

```
 var percoll=new SomeDetails();
    percoll.username=user;
    percoll.SetA=SetA;
    percoll.SetB=SetB;
    //dt repressents DataTable
 if (percoll.SetA.Count > 0 && percoll.SetB.Count > 0)
 {
   dt.Rows.Add(user, SetA[0], SetB[0]);
   var rowcount =SetA.Count > SetB.Count ? SetA.Count : SetB.Count;
   dt = FillDataTable(rowcount, dt, perColl);
 }
 else if (percoll.SetA.Count > 0 && percoll.SetB.Count == 0)
  {
    //Add first row to datatable to get image Format
    //calculate row count
    // call FillDataTable
  }
  else if (percoll.SetA.Count == 0 && percoll.SetB.Count > 0)
  {
    //Add first row to datatable to get image Format
    //calculate row count
    // call FillDataTable
  }
  else
  {
   dt.Rows.Add(user.Key,"-", "-");
  }
```

And FillDatatable is like following manner.

```
 private DataTable FillDataTable(int rowcount, DataTable dt, SomeDetails perColl)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < rowcount; i++)
            {
                string A= "";
                string B= "";

                if (i < perColl.SetA.Count)
                {
                    A= perColl.SetA[i];
                }

                if (i < perColl.SetB.Count)
                {
                    B= perColl.SetB[i];
                }

                dt.Rows.Add("", A, B);
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

***Problem:***  I want to add another column **SetC** to above image. If I Use above method, I need to check 9 if-else conditions, which is not a good choice.
Finally DataTable should be like this [Final Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEeUT.png)

need Suggestions for better code.

Comment: any suggestions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really not sure what you are doing with all these if-else statements but this should do the same as your code.

```
foreach(var datail in AllDetails) { //assuming you have a list of all users
    // get the max row count of all 3 data sets
    var rows = Math.max(datail.SetA.Count, Math.max(datail.SetB.Count, detail.SetC.Count));
    // iterate to "end" of all datasets
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        // show name only for first row
        var name = i == 0 ? detail.username : "";
        // if list has more elements than actual counter i, access the i'th element - otherwise empty string
        var a = i < datails.SetA.Count ? datails.SetA[i] : "";
        var b = i < datails.SetB.Count ? datails.SetB[i] : "";
        var c = i < datails.SetC.Count ? datails.SetC[i] : "";

        // add values to row
        dt.Rows.Add(name, a, b, c);
    }
}
```